# How to find last "K" indexes of vector satisfying condition (Python) ? (Analogue of Matlab's "find" )

Tags: python, numpy

Consider some vector:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.arange(10)
```

Assume we need to find last 2 indexes satisfying some condition.
For example in Matlab it would be written e.g.

```
find(v <5 , 2,'last')
answer =    [ 3 ,    4 ]  (Note: Matlab indexing from 1)
```

**Question:** What would be the clearest way to do that in Python ?

"Nice" solution should STOP search when it finds 2 desired results, it should NOT search over all elements of vector.
So np.where does not seems to be "nice" in that sense.

We can easyly write that using "for", but is there any alternative way ?
I am afraid using "for" since it might be slow (at least it is very much so in Matlab).

Comment: What exactly did you end up with for the solution including `np.where`? Did you try : `np.where(v<5)[0][-2:]`?

Answer (score 2):

Any solution you'd find will iterate over the list even if the loop is 'hidden' inside a function.
The solution to your problem depends on the assumptions you can make e.g. is the list sorted?
for the general case I'd iterate over the loop starting at the end:

```
def find(condition, k, v):
    indices = []
    for i, var in enumerate(reversed(v)):
        if condition(var):
            indices.append(len(v) - i - 1)
            if len(indices) >= k:
                break
    return indices
```

The condition should then be passed as a function, so you can use a lambda:

```
v = range(10)
find(lambda x: x < 5, 3, v)
```

will output

> [4, 3, 2]

Answer (score 2):

This attempt doesn't use `numpy`, and it is probably not very idiomatic.

Nevertheless, if I understand it correctly, `zip`, `filter` and `reversed` are all lazy iterators that take only the elements that they really need. Therefore, you could try this:

```
x = list(range(10))

from itertools import islice

res = reversed(list(map(
  lambda xi: xi[1], 
  islice(
    filter(
      lambda xi: xi[0] < 5, 
      zip(reversed(x), reversed(range(len(x))))
    ), 
    2
  )
)))

print(list(res))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4]
```

What it does (from inside to outside):

- create index range
- reverse both array and indices
- zip the reversed array with indices
- filter the two `(value, index)`-pairs that you need, extract them by `islice`
- Throw away the values, retain only indices with `map`
- reverse again

Even though it looks somewhat monstrous, it should all be lazy, and stop after it finds the first two elements that you are looking for. I haven't compared it with a simple loop, maybe just using a loop would be both simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a "good" numpy solution to short-circuiting.

The most principled way to go would be using something like `Cython` which to brutally oversimplify it adds fast loops to Python. Once you have set that up it would be easy.

If you do not want to do that you'd have to employ some gymnastics like:

```
import numpy as np

def find_last_k(vector, condition, k, minchunk=32):
    if k > minchunk:
        minchunk = k
    l, r = vector.size - minchunk, vector.size
    found = []
    n_found = 0
    while r > 0:
        if l <= 0:
            l = 0
        found.append(l + np.where(condition(vector[l:r]))[0])
        n_found += len(found[-1])
        if n_found >= k:
            break
        l, r = 3 * l - 2 * r, l
    return np.concatenate(found[::-1])[-k:]
```

This tries balancing loop overhead and numpy "inflexibility" by searching in chunks, which we grow exponentially until enough hits are found.

Not exactly pretty, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found that seems to do this job for the example described (using argwhere which returns all indices that meet the criteria and then we find the last two of these as a numpy array):

```
ind = np.argwhere(v<5)
ind[-2:]
```

This searches through the entire array so is not optimal but is easy to code.